# How can I populate some records after my plugin is installed?

Tags: plugin-development, records, installation

When I install the plugin, I need to automatically create a few records. How can I have my plugin automatically create those records when it is installed?

Answer (score 5):

On the main `MyPluginPlugin` class, there is a method you can override called `onAfterInstall()`. Which will run after your plugin is installed.

To create those records, you can place the following code into the method:

```
public function onAfterInstall()
{
    $record = new MyPlugin_ExampleRecord;
    $record->setAttribute('attributeName', 'value');
    $record->save();

    $record2 = new MyPlugin_ExampleRecord;
    $record2->setAttribute('attributeName', 'value2');
    $record2->save();
}
```